# Redirect-related double render error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I am redirecting the user if they are signed out. Then I am pulling a list of professionals.. and need to redirect there too, if none exist. Is there a way to solve this dilemma?

```
  def purchase
    @style = Style.find(params[:id])
    if user_signed_in? && current_user.consumer 
      @professionals = Professional.where(...)
      if @professionals.empty?
        redirect_to style_path(@style)
      else
        ...
      end
      ...
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please sign in as a consumer to access this page"
      redirect_to style_path(@style)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Your code cannot execute both redirect commands, so you should not get a double-render unless you're not showing us all the code.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange... I took some extraneous code out, but nothing that would affect this logic.

Comment: You **ARE** getting double-render error?  One is in the if, the other in the else.

Comment: Do you really have `redirect_to redirect_to style_path(@style)` in your code?

Comment: Haha, I think that was the real problem. Nice one Fred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `and return` so that the action returns and does not continue.  Please try the following:

```
redirect_to style_path(@style) and return
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the above answers, some just prefer the style of

```
return redirect_to style_path(@style)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your following code to this :

```
  if @professionals.empty?
    redirect_to style_path(@style) and return
```

Hope it will help. Thanks